# PC freezes randomly in Windows and Ubuntu, video keeps playing, mouse and keyboard input is ignored

Tags: hardware-failure, freeze

PC starts ignoring mouse and keyboard once per day - it is not a total freeze, because the video keeps playing - the PC is mainly used to play YouTube, but it can also freeze when browsing other websites on the net, this happened once or twice.

PC is a few years old, it has Intel Pentium 8505 and 8 GB of RAM and a 128 GB SSD, no graphic card, a 400W LG power supply, a wired PS2 keyboard, a wired USB mouse.

The same problem happens in Windows 10 and in Ubuntu.

The same problem happens if I disconnect the SSD from the motherboard and start it with a live Linux from USB.

One pass of MemTest86 reported no problems with RAM.

What else can I test?

Comment: Is your keyboard and mouse wireless and if so, do they use the same receiver?

Comment: [Here](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-10-watching-videos-freeze/) is an article that lists 10 things you can try if you are experiencing you type of problem. I would start here.

Comment: wired PS2 keyboard, wired USB mouse

Comment: @Brian All 10 things I could try wouldn't happen on the same PC on Windows, on Ubuntu and on Linux live USB

Comment: I would keep my task manager up while playing video to see how much CPU is being used the next time it freezes. If this problem happens across multiple OSs, it points to a hardware problem. Though, that problem could simply be videos are monopolizing all the CPU resources.

Comment: I can try monitoring CPU usage, but I doubt that a single YouTube video would cause this. Besides, when the freeze happens, the video keeps playing.

Comment: It is a distinct possibility. I have a discrete GPU GeForce 1660 and a 4K video utilizes 50% of the GPU. Video playback can utilize a lot of CPU time - especially when there isn't a discrete GPU. Does the system ever "unfreeze" or do you manually reboot it? Does it remain frozen after the video stop playing?

Comment: I agree that there is a chance of that happening, but the videos play in 480p quality on a HD monitor. No, so far the PC remains unresponsive until I restart the PC manually.

Comment: Does it only freeze on YouTube videos? Can you play other videos locally using a local media player (and does it crash)?

Comment: I think that it can also freeze when browsing other websites on the net, this happened once or twice. I neve tried playing videos locally.

Comment: There are a plethora of problems it could be that technically make this question too broad of a question for this site. Since this only is happening when playing videos and it happens across different platforms, I can only imagine two problems. One, the videos stress your system resources (but 480p shouldn't be too much for a CPU not doing anything else). Two, there is some hardware problem with the motherboard or CPU (but if so, would likely create other problems). But, unless the CPU is continuously spiking when watching videos, these is little direct evidence to support either possibility.

Comment: You've done good troubleshooting by testing OS running from USB, so it's *not* SSD/HDD issue, it's *not* OS issue, it's *not* the browser. That pretty much leaves hardware, whether RAM, PS, heat, etc. Now you might try, 1. Reseat all RAM, and wiggle other connectors to reseat. 2. Test RAM (slow!). 3. Check CPU temps (e.g., with HWinfo).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I did one pass of MemTest86, it reported no problems with RAM - should I do more than one?

Comment: If you ran a *full* test, no need to rerun; you might try https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-memtest64/ for an alternative with GUI. Another thing to test would be CPU/PS load, e.g. with https://www.jam-software.com/heavyload , while checking temp, e.g., with https://www.hwinfo.com/. Of course, use VirusTotal to check software before use: https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload